# Tumblr link to the first and last page pagination

Tags: pagination, tumblr

**I built up a jump pagination with a link to the last and first page in my tumblr theme with these 2 codes :**

`<a href="/page/{TotalPages}">First</a>`

```
<a href="/">Last</a>
```

**The problem is it doesn't work with tag pages it only works in the home page so I tried to modify these codes and it worked for the last page link by changing :**

`<a href="/">Last</a>` **into** `<a href="label">Last</a>`

However I didn't found the solution for the first page link can someone help me ?

My tumblr blog adress is : amadeusjacobs.com

Comment: Your `<a href="label">Last</a>` is 404ing for me. Just thought you should know.

Comment: Guess: Is it a href="{Label}"

Comment: @Archmage it works for me maybe it was a bug

Comment: @lharby No it is not a href="{Label}" but I think it works with this code

Comment: Going to think on this, but quick fixes: `<a href="javascript:window.location = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('/page/'));">Latest</a>` and `<a href="javascript:window.location = window.location.href + '/page/{TotalPages}';">First</a>`

Comment: Also, this should work on index, tag, search, and day pages.

Answer (score 1):

**Tumblr Theme Code Snippet**

```
{block:Pagination}
    <a id="first_page">first</a>
    {block:PreviousPage}
        <a href="{PreviousPage}">prev</a>
    {/block:PreviousPage}
    {block:JumpPagination}
        {block:CurrentPage}
            <span class="current_page">{PageNumber}</span>
        {/block:CurrentPage}
        {block:JumpPage}
            <a class="jump_page" href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a>
        {/block:JumpPage}
    {/block:JumpPagination}
    {block:NextPage}
        <a href="{NextPage}">next</a>
    {/block:NextPage}
    <a id="last_page">last</a>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var f = document.getElementById("first_page"), 
            l = document.getElementById("last_page"),
            p = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/*$/, ""),
            i = p.indexOf("/page/"),
            j = p.length,
            u = i > 0 ? p.substr(0, i) : (i == -1 && j > 0) ? p : "/";
        f.setAttribute("href", u);
        u = u.length == 1 ? "" : u;
        l.setAttribute("href", u + "/page/{TotalPages}");
    </script>
{/block:Pagination}
```

**Notes**

- This is obviously only going to work if the user has JS enabled
- Works for all paginated pages
- For a limited time, you can test this [here](http://wolfspirals.tumblr.com/)

**ETA**

Of course, I had to play with it until I broke it. All cases should be covered, now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ally I'll try it later when I come back from work to see if it works I'll keep you informed :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You made my day ! the code snippet works perfectly !

Comment: For your first answer I tried both codes but the link to the first post code didn't work in the home pages only in the tag pages, but the full pagination code did it ! Thanks again !

Comment: Hey @Ally I would like to put an upper pagination but when I do that the links "last" and "first" dont work anymore only the <a href="javascript:window.location = window.location.href.substr(0,window.location.href.indexOf('/page/'));">Latest</‌​a> and <a href="javascript:window.location = window.location.href + '/page/{TotalPages}';">First</a> work but the "first" code works only in tag pages

Comment: I am pretty sure everything you are trying to do is part of the native tumblr template.

Comment: @lharby I couldn't find this full code snippet Tumblr docs don't have all this

Comment: @lharby And you'd be incorrect. I wouldn't have went to this trouble if it was included.

Comment: @Amadeus The first "quick" solution doesn't actually work because it doesn't have all the extraneous case checking like the solution does.

Comment: @Ally got it :) is there a way to make it work twice I would like to paste the code above posts to have double pagination but when I do that the "first" and "last" buttons in the pagination below posts don't respond anymore like if the JS can only load once